# split/divide main content region to columns or create another custom layout

Tags: theming

I am building a theme and I want my main content region to be divided in 3 fixed columns. I have produced all my .css code and I just want to dynamically produce the markup (3 columns) and attach my styles to them. I know 'use panels or display suite' is the easy answer but I haven't till found a way to use them effectively.

Ideally I would have regions: content-left, content-center, content-right and when I create content I can choose where to place it. this `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` needs some tweaking! Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching, I was lucky (and persisent enough!) to come across this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmX2jnH9Kdg which describes how to achieve what I am after using panels indeed. I feel covered by that excellent video. I can leave my Q up for anyone frustrated as to how to translate his/her layout to dynamic drupal code